# How to use regression algorithm to predict attribute?

Tags: machine-learning, weka

I am creating a simple AI which predicts mac numbers. Problem is I couldn't find any regression algorithm to find the correct relation between com, mac and result. It only has %3 prediction ratio. What is the problem with my code?

```
DataSource source = new DataSource("mydata.arff");
Instances traindata = source.getDataSet();
traindata.setClassIndex(traindata.numAttributes() - 2);

REPTree repTree = new REPTree();
repTree.buildClassifier(traindata);

Instance dataToPredict = traindata.lastInstance();
double result = repTree.classifyInstance(dataToPredict);
```

Here is my sample Data;

```
@attribute com numeric
@attribute mac numeric
@attribute result {yes, no}

@data
12,28,no
22,58,no
30,70,yes
37,63,yes
32,68,yes
31,69,yes
7,27,no
30,?,yes
```

**EDIT:** Relation is so easy.

```
If result is true then mac = 100 - com
```

Comment: What is the relation when result is false?

Comment: @Nogoseke when result is false it means mac != 100 - com

Comment: Bu what should your model learn for this case? A random number? If the model predicted 1000000 when result is false would it be right? it is different then 100 - com.

Comment: @Nogoseke Yes of course 100000 is correct if result is false. Maybe I don't get the basic idea of ML.

Comment: Think of your regression problem as if you are trying to learn how to approximate a function. Your examples are of the kind f(x) = y. x being your inputs and y what want to predict. If for some values of x your y is random, what kind of function f can approximate this? Perhaps you can only use examples that have result=true.